# Sympy: Multiplications of exponential rather than exponential of sum

Tags: python, sum, multiplication, sympy, exponential

I'm searching how to tell SymPy to use a multiplication of exponentials rather than an exponential of a sum. That is, it currently gives me exp(a + b) and I would want to get exp(a)*exp(b). There must be a fairly easy way but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Can you post the specific sympy calls you are making?

Comment: Do you have to use sympy? Can you run the calculations without it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`expand()`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.expand) function to show the expression with multiplication of bases rather than the sum of exponents:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a, b = symbols('a b')
>>> expr = exp(a + b)
>>> expr
exp(a + b)
>>> expr.expand()
exp(a)*exp(b)
```

The documentation for this function is [here](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.4/modules/core.html#sympy.core.function.expand). The relevant parts are summarised below:

> `sympy.core.function.expand(e, deep=True, modulus=None, power_base=True, power_exp=True, mul=True, log=True, multinomial=True, basic=True, **hints)`
>
> Expand an expression using methods given as hints.
>
> Hints evaluated unless explicitly set to False are:  `basic`, `log`,
>       `multinomial`, `mul`, `power_base`, and `power_exp` ...

It's clear that `power_exp` is the relevant hint:

> `power_exp`
>
> Expand addition in exponents into multiplied bases.
>
> ```
> >>> exp(x + y).expand(power_exp=True)
> exp(x)*exp(y)
> >>> (2**(x + y)).expand(power_exp=True)
> 2**x*2**y
> ```

Turning it to `False` leaves the expression unchanged:

```
>>> expr.expand(power_exp=False)
exp(a + b)
```