# Multiplication of exponential to exponential of the sum in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

How can an expression of the form exp(a * x) * exp(b * x) be transformed to exp(a * x +b * x) using sympy?

The starting point would be something like:

```
from sympy import symbols, exp
from sympy import exp
x, a, b = symbols('x, a, b', real=True)
f = exp(a*x)*exp(b*x)
```

The inverse transformation has been explained in [1]

[1] [Sympy: Multiplications of exponential rather than exponential of sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117770/sympy-multiplications-of-exponential-rather-than-exponential-of-sum)

Comment: From your code, I think you want that `exp(a*x)*exp(b*x)` become `exp((a+b)*x)`, right?

Comment: exp(a*x + b*x) is fine too. As long as there is only one exp is fine for what I am trying now. (i edited the question to correct two typos).

Answer (score 3):

I found that `powsimp` could do what you want

```
from sympy import symbols, exp
from sympy import exp, powsimp
x, a, b = symbols('x, a, b', real=True)
f = exp(a*x)*exp(b*x)
powsimp(f)
```

**Output**

```
exp(a*x + b*x)
```

`powdenest` also (in this case) do the same

[Reference](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#powsimp) to `powsimp`

[Reference](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#powdenest) to `powdenest`

Answer (score 2):

The `simplify` command does the job

```
from sympy import symbols, simplify, exp
x, a, b = symbols('x, a, b', real=True)
f = exp(a*x)*exp(b*x)
fs = simplify(f)
```

**Output**

```
>>> f
exp(ax)exp(bx)
>>> fs
exp(x(a + b))
```